# Error in passing a date from MySQL to Java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, date

I have a problem with passing dates from a MySQL query to Java using the CreateSQLQuery function.
Specifically, I have this query:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT DISTINCT year(data_inizio_commessa_utente) as anno_inizio_commessa, month(data_inizio_commessa_utente) as mese_inizio_commessa, "
                                        + "ifnull(year(data_fine_commessa_utente), year(current_date)) as anno_fine_commessa, ifnull(month(data_fine_commessa_utente), month(current_date)) as mese_fine_commessa " 
                                        + "FROM rel_utenti_commesse WHERE (year(data_inizio_commessa_utente) = '" + anno + "' or year(data_fine_commessa_utente) = '" + anno + "' or '" + anno + "' between year(data_inizio_commessa_utente) and year(data_fine_commessa_utente)) and "
                                        + "fk_id_utente = '" + id_utente + "'")
        .addScalar("anno_inizio_commessa", new IntegerType())
        .addScalar("mese_inizio_commessa", new IntegerType())
        .addScalar("anno_fine_commessa", new IntegerType())
        .addScalar("mese_inizio_commessa", new IntegerType());

List<Object[]> resultSet = query.list();

for(int i = 0; i < resultSet.size(); i++) {
    int anno_inizio_commessa = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.get(i)[0].toString());
    int mese_inizio_commessa = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.get(i)[1].toString());
    int anno_fine_commessa = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.get(i)[2].toString());
    int mese_fine_commessa = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.get(i)[3].toString());

    System.out.println(anno_inizio_commessa);
    System.out.println(mese_inizio_commessa);
    System.out.println(anno_fine_commessa);
    System.out.println(mese_fine_commessa);
}
```

Now, to the system the output is this:

```
2018
11
2019
11
2019
1
2019
1
```

But if I run the query on MySQL the result is this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
## anno1 ## ## mese1 ## ## anno2 ## ## mese2 ##

   2018         11          2019         1
   2019         1           2019         2
--------------------------------------------------
```

The same error happens to me when I try to print the output a date in the format (YYYY-MM-DD).

Specifically, if I have a 2018-01-01 date in the database, after having done the .toString () of the cell, I get out in 2017-12-31.
In practice, time goes back one day.

Why?

Comment: Simplify your example code to the minimum needed to demonstrate your issue. Make a contrived example rather than paste your project code.

Comment: Can you verify the timezone set for the MySQL column and the timezone used by java run?

Comment: @BasilBourqueHow can I check the two different timezone?